# Python filter one list based on values that do not exist in another list

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, ms-access, pypyodbc

Trying to filter results of a query on a Table A by 2 values not found in a Table B. What would be the proper syntax and approach?

```
 import pyodbc
 MDB = 'C:/db/db1.mdb'; DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'; PWD = 'pw'
 con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,MDB,PWD))
 cur = con.cursor()
 SQLA = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1;' # your query goes here
 SQLB = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE2;' # your query goes here
 rows1 = cura.execute(SQLA).fetchall()
 rows2 = cura.execute(SQLB).fetchall()
 cur.close()
 con.close()
 for rit in rows1: 
     for git in rows2: 
        if (rit[1] and rit[2]) not in (git[1] and git[2]):
           print ((rit[1])  (rit[2]))
```

Comment: Does this code work? If so, are you asking for improvements? If not, what is broken?

Comment: Nope when ran it prints out all the rows in TABLE1 which shouldnt be the situation.

Comment: I think you need to add the ORDER BY clause to your select statements. Also, for it to work the first two columns in both of your tables need to match

Comment: @BKCapri - So do you want to list just the value pairs from `TABLE1` that do not exist in `TABLE2`? (If so, then that's not a "sort", it's a filter.)

Comment: I after all the rows in Table1 where a value pair from Table1 isnt found in Table2.

Comment: How would I get to filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a pure SQL solution with the familiar `LEFT JOIN... IS NULL / NOT EXISTS / NOT IN`. Below are equivalent queries, compliant in MS Access, returning rows in TableA not in TableB based on *col1* and *col2*.

**LEFT JOIN...IS NULL**

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM TABLEA a
LEFT JOIN TABLEB b
ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE b.col1 IS NULL AND b.col2 IS NULL
```

**NOT EXISTS**

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM TABLEA a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB b
   WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2)
```

**NOT IN**

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM TABLEA a
WHERE a.col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM TABLEB)
AND a.col2 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM TABLEB)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statements offered by Parfait are the preferred solution, but if you really wanted to use your double-loop approach it would need to be more like this:

```
for rit in rows1:
    match_found = False
    for git in rows2: 
        if (rit[1] == git[1]) and (rit[2] == git[2]):
            match_found = True
            break
    if not match_found:
        print(rit)
```

Comment: Still got all the rows in row1 returned.

Comment: @BKCapri - Check the values returned by `rit[1]`, `rit[2]`, `git[1]`, `git[2]`; they may not be what you think they are. (Indexes into those rows will be zero-based, so the first element in `rit` is `rit[0]` not `rit[1]`.)

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo I what I meant was print(rit) still returns all rows from TABLE1

Comment: @BKCapri - There must be some other mistake in your code. It works fine for me.